# AS3 do 3 random stops, that are never equal to one another

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 3 movieclips, each one has 7 frames and labels that play different images, I want to stop each one randomly, but never have them equal the same frame. I was thinking array.push once its called, but I dont know how to do that. So I have this so far:

```
function startGame(event:MouseEvent)
{
    addChild(level6_mc);
    addChild(inGameNav_mc);
    level6_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
    var timer = setTimeout(startAgain, 1000);
    startAgain();
}


// level 6
function startAgain()
{
    var randomNumber:Number= Math.floor(Math.random()*7);
    var door1 = level6_mc.door1_mc;
    var door2 = level6_mc.door2_mc;
    var door3 = level6_mc.door3_mc;
    door1.gotoAndStop(randomNumber);
    door2.gotoAndStop(randomNumber);
    door3.gotoAndStop(randomNumber);
}
```

there has to be an easy way for this, I just cant figure it out. I have been looking all over the net for a solution, but every method is just so complicated. Can anyone help me find a simple solution, and if you tell me to use an array can you please give example. Thanks in advance

Comment: To clarify, you want the door mc's to all go to a random frame, but not the same frame as one another?  Like, one could be on frame 1, one on frame3 and one on frame4, but no two on the same frame at the same time?

Comment: yes, and if its easy to make one frame always be present. such as frame 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would opt for an approach like this:

```
function startGame(event:MouseEvent){
    addChild(level6_mc);
    addChild(inGameNav_mc);
    level6_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
    var timer= setTimeout(startAgain, 1000);
    startAgain();
}

function startAgain(){
    var randomFrames:Array = getRandomFrames(3);
    var door1 = level6_mc.door1_mc;
    var door2 = level6_mc.door2_mc;
    var door3 = level6_mc.door3_mc;
    door1.gotoAndStop(randomFrames[0]);
    door2.gotoAndStop(randomFrames[1]);
    door3.gotoAndStop(randomFrames[2]);
}


/*
   Given input of 3, the return should be an array of integers randomly 
   chosen from the array defined by `frames`.  An example would be `[5,2,7]`
*/
function getRandomFrames(var $frameCount:Number):Array {
    var frames:Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    var randomFrames:Array = new Array(Math.min($frameCount, frames.length));

    var pos:Number = 0;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < randomFrames.length; i++)
    {
        pos = int(Math.random() * frames.length);
        randomFrames[i] = frames.splice(pos, 1)[0];
    }
    return randomFrames
}
```

I don't have Flash on this machine, so I can't test.  But the idea is that you have an array of frame numbers, 1-7 and you randomly choose 3 of those numbers to be your stop frames.

Comment: I get a syntax error here (expecting identifier before var function getRandomFrames(var $frameCount:Int):Array

Comment: I think `Int` may have needed to be `int`.  Anyway, I replaced with `Number` type instead which I know is capitalized.  There may be other syntax errors as I said I couldn't test.  But this answer is about the right way to solve a problem.

Comment: well thank you sir, I am still getting syntax errors, but nothing a few minutes of searching cant find. Thank you man, you are awesome. I love the logic behind this.

Comment: The problem was you had letters.length in your second var, when it should be frames.length. So all is good and its working like a charm. Also I noticed you had a $ before the var, which is as3, I dont think thats necessary. Thanks again

Comment: any ideas to what this error comes from : RangeError: Error #1005: Array index is not a positive integer (NaN).

Answer (score 1):

Since its a small frame count, you can splice the frames out of an array:

```
function startGame(event:MouseEvent){
        addChild(level6_mc);
        addChild(inGameNav_mc);
        level6_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
        var timer= setTimeout(startAgain, 1000);
        startAgain();
    }


    //level 6
    function startAgain(){
            var door1 = level6_mc.door1_mc;
            var door2 = level6_mc.door2_mc;
            var door3 = level6_mc.door3_mc;
            var stopsAt:Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
            door1.gotoAndStop(stopsAt.splice(Math.random()*stopsAt.length, 1)[0]);
            door2.gotoAndStop(stopsAt.splice(Math.random()*stopsAt.length, 1)[0]);
            door3.gotoAndStop(stopsAt.splice(Math.random()*stopsAt.length, 1)[0]);
```

Comment: haha man you are a simple minded person. This is smooth, works great. Lighter too, How could I say that I always want frame 2 to be one of the random stops on a random door? does that make sense?

Comment: @diskrim To achieve that you should generate the `stopsAt` items. Your array can start with the number `2` already on position 0, and the populate the two remaining positions on a while loop avoiding repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var prevNum:int = 0;

function startGame(event:MouseEvent)
{
addChild(level6_mc);
addChild(inGameNav_mc);
level6_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
var timer = setTimeout(startAgain, 1000);
startAgain();
}
```

// level 6

```
function startAgain()
{
var randomNumber:int= getRandomNumber(7,prevNum);
prevNum = randomNumber;
var door1 = level6_mc.door1_mc;
var door2 = level6_mc.door2_mc;
var door3 = level6_mc.door3_mc;
door1.gotoAndStop(randomNumber);
door2.gotoAndStop(randomNumber);
door3.gotoAndStop(randomNumber);
}

function getRandomNumber(length:int,previousNumber:int):int
{ 
    var currentNumber:int;
    do{

  currentNumber = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*length);

}while(currentNumber==previousNumber);

return currentNumber;
}
```

Comment: nice man. thanks for that. I used something else, but this logic is really helpful for many reasons. Thanks for taking a look at this.